# Pandas - Function to have to tell if event happened on consecutive days

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, diff

I am a beginner learning the Pandas library. I have a table where I want to calculate if a team has played

1. On Consecutive Days
2. 4 in 5 nights.

My data set looks like the following<

```
DATE   HOME_TEAM   AWAY_TEAM   BACK_TO_BACK  FOUR_IN_FIVE

2015-10-26  DET ATL         0
2015-10-27  ATL DET         1
2015-10-27  CHI CLE         0
2015-10-27  GSW NOP         0
2015-10-28  LAL MIN         0
2015-10-28  SAC LAC         0
```

So if ATL played the night before as either a home team or away team, I want to create a new feature that indicates this is the case. I use apply a lot, but I am stuck in this current situation. The next step would be going back say 5 days and see if a team has played in 4 nights. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your desired output? Would you have one (eventually two) column per team?

Comment: Sure Ian. Sorry about that. Thanks!

Comment: What happens if Detroit ended up playing on 10-28 and so did Cleveland? i.e. what would be the back_to_back count?

Comment: Correct. So if a team played EITHER HOME or AWAY on  10-27 and  EITHER HOME or AWAY that would be a 1(YES) and 0(NO).